# Getting error while installing packages for -npm install --save-dev protractor-cucumber-framework

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor, cucumber, angular6

> Basically I am trying to use `protractor-cucumber-html-report` plugin
>   in my protractor automation project. For that I am installing the
>   required npm packages for generating cucumber as report below -

```
npm install --save-dev protractor-cucumber-framework

npm install --save-dev cucumber

npm install --save-dev chai

npm install --save-dev chai-as-promised

npm install --save-dev @types/cucumber

npm install --save-dev @types/chai

npm install --save-dev @types/chai-as-promised
```

---

But somehow while installation i am getting error as below :

```
 329 verbose type range
    330 verbose stack domino: No matching version found for domino@^2.0.1
    330 verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:65:11)
    330 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:52:18)
    330 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    330 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    330 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    330 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    330 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    330 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    330 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    330 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\bkodalkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    330 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    330 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    330 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
    331 verbose cwd C:\Source\WK.RetailInterview\WK.RetailInterview\ClientApp
    332 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    333 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\bkodalkar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@angular/cli@latest"
    334 verbose node v8.11.2
    335 verbose npm  v5.6.0
    336 error code ETARGET
    337 error notarget No matching version found for domino@^2.0.1
    338 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
    338 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
    338 error notarget
    338 error notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular/platform-server'
    339 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried solution to install dependent packages and latest npm, but no luck , can you please help me?

```
npm i domino@2.0.1
npm i @angular/platform-server
```

Here is my package.json dependency list:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "domino": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0"
  }
```

Comment: Same error when installing -npm install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

I also got an error (ERR 1) when running:

```
npm install -save--dev domino@^2.0.1
```

But adding it to the package.json:

```
"domino": "^2.0.1",
```

And running a plain:

```
npm install
```

Worked fine - and subsequently running the npm install command worked.

Comment: I tried with same steps you mentioned above and still facing same error

Comment: Error after runningcommand-->  npm install                                                  C:\Source\ClientApp>npm install
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for domino@^2.0.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you share your package.json (or at least the dependencies bit) so I can try and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry i have added all dependency-in splitted format as i dont know how to attach file here in comment, And i have changed version name of domino in current file to ^2.0.1 , just to check above mentioned solution

Comment: my system currently installed domino is -domino:"^1.1.0.rc-1" and i can not uninstall domino even

Comment: I have moved all of those into your question, so feel free to delete out the comments. Can you delete your `node_modules` folder entirely and then run `npm install` in the folder containing your package.json file? This worked for me.

Comment: i already tried npm install after deleting nod modules but that is not worked for me